# regarding transaction commit in mysql?

Tags: mysql

My server configuration has auto_commit = off which helps in large transaction while inserting and updating but what if innodb_autoinc_lock_mode = 1 as my tables does not have primary key with auto_increment? will it help in faster results or do we need to make to 2? is there any way to help it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Beyond some point, waiting too long to `COMMIT` slows things down.  Think of it as having to save more and more "undo" stuff.

`innodb_autoinc_lock_mode` only applies to `AUTO_INCREMENT`.

It seems that your *real* question is about high speed ingestion.  Are you `INSERTing` one row at a time?  You can get 10x speedup if you insert 100 at a time.  That is, a single `INSERT` with 100 rows.  Are you inserting from multiple connections?  Etc.  Here's [*one discussion*](http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/staging_table) on high speed ingestion.

Comment: Yes im inserting more than 15 Millions of rows of data through load data in file from Talend application ,It is faster but  on server end,i just getting 750 rows/sec while on test environment 2500 rows/sec , thing is same configuration file on both end , Any suggestion please?

Comment: Both are through Talend?  Dig deeper; something is different.  Diff `SHOW VARIABLES`; check RAM sizes; Talend options; other activity on machine; etc.